# show notification in particular time every day

Tags: java, android, notifications

Hello guys (First : sorry for my poor English) 
I searched a lot and still did not find any answer 
 
I want to show a status-bar notification every day at 09:00 A.M (**easiest** way please) 
This is my notification :

```
private void showNotification(){

            NotificationCompat.Builder myNotification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, "1");

            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, i, 0);

            myNotification.setAutoCancel(true);
            myNotification.setDefaults(NotificationCompat.DEFAULT_ALL);
            myNotification.setWhen(20000);
            myNotification.setTicker("Ticker");
            myNotification.setContentInfo("Info");
            myNotification.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
            myNotification.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.height);
            myNotification.setContentTitle("New notification title");
            myNotification.setContentText("Notification text");
            myNotification.setSound(RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION));

            NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            notificationManager.notify(1, myNotification.build());

}
```

Now how to call this function everyday at 09:00 A.M ?
(again , show me the easiest way :) )

Answer (score 0):

Old way is to use AlarmIntentService. New way (Oreo) is to use JobScheduler.

Comment: the main question is how?! (for JobScheduler) 
if you can show me a simple example

Comment: See this tutorial: https://medium.com/google-developers/scheduling-jobs-like-a-pro-with-jobscheduler-286ef8510129